# Möbius transformations - triangles

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Is there a Möbius transformation which maps the sides of the triangle with vertices at $−1$, $i$ and $1$ to the sides
of an equilateral triangle (all sides equal)?

Thanks!

Comment: No - the only Mobius transformations that sends the **sides** of any triangle all to the **sides** of another triangle are the translations $f(z)=z+b$, and since your original triangle is not equilateral, no translation of it is equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

Mobius transformations (like any other holomorphic transformation) conserve angles, so that's not possible.

However, there are some that map the vertices $1,i,-i$ to the vertices of an equilateral triangle (and the sides of the original triangle to some arcs)